# Writing clean URLS with 1 parameter that point to page.php

Tags: .htaccess, clean-urls

I would like when visitors type `http://localhost/mywebsite/paris/`
it calls `http://localhost/mywebsite/page.php?city=paris`

But when typed `http://localhost/mywebsite/`
it calls to `http://localhost/mywebsite/index.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z-]*) /page.php?city=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I get the following error :

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

Comment: Please share more details. Why should `http://localhost/mywebsite/`  yield something else than the index if you haven't defined any rule for that? Your requirement is to match `http://localhost/mywebsite/paris/`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ page.php?city=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ page.php?city=$1
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.